# Giving user profile pages unique url ids PHP

Tags: php

I've made a user profile page. Using the code written below. I'm trying to give each users profile page a unique id/url that so it is viewable by others.

Is this the right technique to use or is there a more practical one?

```
    <?php  session_start(); 

   if(isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) && $_SESSION['signed_in'] == true)
{   
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/inc/database3.php");

$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$useremail = $_SESSION['useremail'];
$userdate = $_SESSION['userdate'];

$pageTitle = $username . '&#39;s Profile';

$pageCategory = $username . '&#39;s Profile'; /* &#39; */
$pageCategoryurl = '/profile.php';

include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/inc/header.php"); 
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/inc/search.php");




echo '<div class="content">';

    echo '<h2 align="center">' . $username . '&#39;s Profile</h2>';
    echo '<ul class="ulstyle">';
    echo '<li>Your user id number is ' . $userid . '.</li>';    
    echo '<li>Your user name is ' . $username . '.</li>';       
    echo '<li>Your email address is ' . $useremail . '.</li>';
    echo '<li>The date you signed up for this website was on ' . $userdate . '.</li>';
    echo '</ul>';

echo '</div>';

 include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/inc/footer.php"); 


    }
    else
     {
         header('Location: /signin.php');
     }


    ?>
```

Comment: this page will only be viewable to login user and not others right ?

Comment: Give an example of url you want for your users. Will it be `www.example.com/1` or `www.example.com/username`?

Comment: Currently it is set up to show only the logged in user. I'd like for other users to be able to see it as well. I'd like the url to be either www.example.com/profile.php?userid=282753 or www.example.com/username.